# Laravel 5 - generate not working

Tags: php, laravel-5, sublimetext3

I am using Laravel 5 Extended Generators for sublime text 3
it gives me the error

```
  [InvalidArgumentException]                                  
  There are no commands defined in the "generate" namespace.
```

I Installed it with `Composer` and added the `Service Provider`
from this site: [Laravel 5 Extended Generators](https://github.com/laracasts/Laravel-5-Generators-Extended)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to expect to use `generate`. The documentation says:

> You're all set. Run `php artisan` from the console, and you'll see the
>   new commands in the make:* namespace section.